# Substitutes for OSR Driver Loader (windows kernel driver )

Tags: virtualbox, wdk

I  build a kernel driver sample on VisualStudio and I attempt to deploy and debug it.

PC's environment : windows10 64bit pro ,visualstudio2017, wdk 1803

I don't have 2 PCs, so I want to deploy and debug on virtual machines 
for example VirtualBox.

I'm still learning windows kernel device driver following to [a windows kernel driver programing tutorial's youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUlbYRFFYf0&list=PLZ4EgN7ZCzJx2DRXTRUXRrB2njWnx1kA2)

I attempt to download OSR Driver Loader , but error messages appears:

> "The Lists are moving! Logins to this site are disabled.
>   For details see this post in the OSR Devs Blog."

I searching driver loader the site  of the link destination,but I can't find it.

Does substitutes for Driver Loader exist ?
Please give a answer to the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Peter_Viscarola's comment](https://community.osr.com/discussion/comment/290720/#Comment_290720) from OSR community:

> Right now, you can't. We're in the process of trying to determine what to do with these hideously old, legacy, utilities. We haven't touched them in years and, to be frank, I'm not even sure we have the sources for some of these anymore. If we can find the sources, we'll probably move the sources for the innocuous and useless utilities to GitHub so people can do whatever they want with them, which hopefully will not including mocking our command of writing applications, 20 years ago, using MFC and C++. Some utilities which are complex and disruptive (I'm thinking of my favorites DeviceTree and IrpTracker) we may just stop distributing entirely.
>
> Like most of the utilities on OSRONLINE, OSR Driver Loader was nice when it was written, which was like 20 years ago. Now, it provides very close to zero value. IIRC, there is nothing you can do with Driver Loader that you can't do today using the "SC" command.

You can though find some mirrors on the internet by googling the loader's full filename in quotes `"osrloaderv30.zip"`. I found one [here](http://coinz.tistory.com/218) (or [direct link](http://coinz.tistory.com/attachment/fk030000000000.zip)) but I woudln't recommend downloading it from unknown locations actually, up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the information. 　I'm going to use it as an reference.